# How to parse json data present in a google sheet cell as data form

Tags: json, parsing, google-sheets

How to parse json data present in a google sheet cell as data form.

I have exported a csv file where one of the column has form data in json format. I have copied that file in google sheet, how do I parse data of that specific column which has data in json format.

e.g.

Data in one of the cells looks like this

```
"utf8":"\u2713",
   "authenticity_token":"[object Object]",
   "task_id":"21",
   "number_input_ACB70B69-6E86-420E-AAB4-263A335795DE":"33",
   "text_input_3ABA1E2D-9726-4B9C-9EAB-85E5D93BE47B":"volunteer at aNGO",
   "text_input_0A5BE0C2-0745-40C8-831B-5FDDE49B5353":"B.architecture",
   "text_area_3FE1D3FE-FC9E-4370-90F2-3D86C4DA2243":"A little knowledge on classical dance"
```

I just need four fields from above data :

1. text input - 33
2. text input - volunteer at aNGO
3. text input - B.architecture
4. text area  - A little knowledge on classical dance

Comment: I cannot propose the concrete proposal because I'm not sure about your detail situation from your question. I apologize for this. When you want to parse the JSON data of the string value in the cell, how about using Google Apps Script? When Google Apps Script is used, the JSON data retrieved from the cell can be parsed. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you, I will read on Google API Script to learn and will respond to you.
Can you share some online resource which explains how to use Google API Script for parsing Json retrieved data.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. I think that you can see several sample scripts and how to use Google Apps Script at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info). And, when I saw your sample data and the values you expect, do you want to retrieve the values from each key? By the way, in the case of your sample data, `text input - 33` is number_input - 33`? If you need a help in your creating script, feel free to tell us. We will support you.

Comment: @Tanaike I need to retrieve data for all the four values (am not sure if those are called keys) There are four data inputs and I need all four in separate columns.I would need help in creating the script. it will be great if you can help. Meanwhile I will read the link that you have shared.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I need to retrieve data for all the four values (am not sure if those are called keys) There are four data inputs and I need all four in separate columns.`, when your sample input value is used, can I ask you about the result you want to retrieve?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, I need to share the final column wise details from Json data. 

If you look at the Json data example that I have shared in my original question you will get some idea: Here are four values that I want in four different Columns 1) Number Input 2) Text input 3) Text Input  4) Text Area. 

These four fields values I need.

Answer (score 3):

Apps Script uses a version of Javascript, so you can [retrieve a key](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) from a JSON like:

`json.key` or `json["key"]`

The issue with your json in the Cell, is that it's lacking the initial and end brackets `{` and `}`, so in order to make this to work, you need to add them. Otherwise it won't be considered a JSON object but a regular String. It should look like this:

```
{"utf8":"\u2713",
   "authenticity_token":"[object Object]",
   "task_id":"21",
   "number_input_ACB70B69-6E86-420E-AAB4-263A335795DE":"33",
   "text_input_3ABA1E2D-9726-4B9C-9EAB-85E5D93BE47B":"volunteer at aNGO",
   "text_input_0A5BE0C2-0745-40C8-831B-5FDDE49B5353":"B.architecture",
   "text_area_3FE1D3FE-FC9E-4370-90F2-3D86C4DA2243":"A little knowledge on classical dance"}
```

This would get the value of the keys to write them in 4 separate columns:

```
function main(){


  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Your sheet name");

  var string = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue(); //The cell with the json

  var json = JSON.parse(string); //Converts the string to JSON object


  sheet.getRange("B1:E1").setValues([[json["number_input_ACB70B69-6E86-420E-AAB4-263A335795DE"], json["text_input_3ABA1E2D-9726-4B9C-9EAB-85E5D93BE47B"], json["text_input_0A5BE0C2-0745-40C8-831B-5FDDE49B5353"], json["text_area_3FE1D3FE-FC9E-4370-90F2-3D86C4DA2243"]]]);


}
```

**References:**

- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Comment: Thank you Jescanellas, I need to just run this script. Am I right?

Comment: Yes! Make sure you add the brackets `{, }` to the json string, and adapt the Sheet Name and the Cells from the Script to yours.